# Filter for rows if any value in a list of substrings is contained in any column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, substring

Suppose I have a dataframe df as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Index': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   'Name': ['A', 'B', 100, 'C', 'D'],
                   'col1': [np.nan, 'bbby', 'cccy', 'dddy', 'EEEEE'],
                   'col2': ['water', np.nan, 'WATER', 'soil', 'cold air'],
                   'col3': ['watermelone', 'hot AIR', 'air conditioner', 'drink', 50000],
                  'Results': [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000]})


Out

Index  Name  col1     col2         col3           Results
    1  A     NaN    water       watermelone        1000
    2  B     bbbY    NaN         hot AIR           2000
    3  100   cccY    water       air conditioner   3000
    4  C     dddf    soil        drink             4000
    5  D     EEEEE   cold air    50000             5000
```

I have a list: `matches = ['wat','air']`

How can I choose all rows with `col1` or `col2` or `col3` containing `i` in `matches`.

Expected output:

```
Index  Name  col1     col2         col3           Results
    1  A     NaN     water       watermelone       1000
    2  B     bbbY    NaN         hot AIR           2000
    3  100   cccY    water       air conditioner   3000

    5  D     EEEEE   cold air    50000              5000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.T` to transpose the dataframe and `str.contains` to check the values column-wise and then transpose back (also `str.contains` can have multiple values passed to if separated with `|`, which is why I change the list to a string with `matches = '|'.join(matches)`).

The benefit of transposing the dataframe is that you can use column-wise pandas method instead of looping through rows or a long `lambda x:` list comprehension. `This technique should have good performance` compared to a `lambda x` with `axis=1` answer:

```
# df = df.set_index('Index')
matches = ['wat','air']
matches = '|'.join(matches)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True).T.fillna('')
df = df.T[[df[col].str.lower().str.contains(matches).values.any() for col in df.columns]]
df
Out[1]: 
  Name   col1      col2             col3
0    A            water      watermelone
1    B   bbbY                    hot AIR
2    B   cccY     water  air conditioner
4    D  EEEEE  cold air              eat
```

Comment: @Joe can you change `df = df.T` to `df = df.T.fillna('')` -- see my updated answer.

Comment: @Joe I saw you updated your question. I added `.fillna('')` to deal with blanks and and pass `case=False` to `str.contains()` to ignore uppercase versus lowercase.

Comment: Hi @David Erickson, thanks indeed. I run another big dataset, gave me `"None of [Float64Index([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,\n              ...\n              nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],\n             dtype='float64', length=4237)] are in the [columns]"`.

Comment: @Joe it looks like you have a float and nans on your index. See my updated answer. I have reset the index with `.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: Hi @David Erickson, it seems because there are float numbers in my database, can't match strings. I added `df = df.applymap(str)`. OK now. Much appreciated!!!

Comment: @DavidErickson take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I would do it:

```
df.loc[(df.apply(lambda x: any(m in str(v).lower() 
                               for v in x.values 
                               for m in matches), axis=1))]
```

Here is a efficiency comparison test with @David Erikson answer on a 50,000 row dataframe on a 15 core cpu setup:

```
test_df = pd.concat([df]*10000)
test_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
%timeit result_df = test_df.loc[(test_df.apply(lambda x: any(m in str(v).lower() for v in x.values for m in matches), axis=1))]

455 ms ± 5.48 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

matchess = '|'.join(matches)
%timeit test_df = test_df.reset_index(drop=True).T.fillna('')

2.97 s ± 14.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit test_df_T = test_df_T.applymap(str)

7.94 s ± 140 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit result_df_2 = test_df.T[[test_df[col].str.lower().str.contains(matchess).values.any() for col in test_df.columns]]

28 s ± 1.6 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So just the last line of the second method is more than 56 times slower. (all together ~80 times slower)

Comment: What’s the reason that your code has increased performance? Generally speaking, using pandas methods are more performant, so I don’t know why the methods I have used are less performant than your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as well:

```
df = df[df['col1'].str.contains('|'.join(matches))|df['col2'].str.contains('|'.join(matches))|df['col3'].str.contains('|'.join(matches))]
```

Prints:

```
  Name   col1      col2             col3
1    A   aadY     water      watermelone
2    B   bbbY       air          hot AIR
3    B   cccY     water  air conditioner
5    D  EEEEE  cold air              eat
```

Comment: #What_Would_Brute_Force_Look_like